# What pros would upgrading to Superuser Elite bring?

Tags: superuser

I somewhat understand what Superuser does, but I'm curious if upgrading to the Elite version is a good idea... What pros are there? Does upgrading provide any additional features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the advantages from the [developer's home page](http://androidsu.com/elite/).

Superuser Elite is the Premium version of Superuser. It unlocks several premium features within Superuser, including:

- PIN Protection – Secure your Superuser prompt with a PIN number so that nobody but you can grant Superuser rights to apps
- Access timeout – Allow an app to maintain Superuser rights for a set amount of time, so that you can allow certain apps access without having to remember them or press allow multiple times
- Ghost mode – Hide Superuser from your app tray and home screen. With ghost mode activated, the only way to launch it is by dialing a secret code into the dialer. The default secret code is `*#*#787378737#*#*`, but it can be set to whatever you want. Note that this feature will probably be disabled if your device does not have a dialer (tablets specifically).
- Advanced log management – Set the log to only store a certain number of entries before deleting the oldest entry. You also gain the ability to set certain apps to not log at all.
- Advanced notification management – Set which apps send notifications and which apps don’t
- Toast notification placement – If you choose to use Toast notifications instead of Status bar notifications, you gain the ability to set where the notification will appear; top, bottom, or center of the screen, or the default location

Comment: I got it for the PIN protection and for beta access (which I believe is over), and of course to support Chainfire.  So far it's been great and the binary updater came in handy a few times before it made it into the standard version.

Comment: Thanks! I really had no idea what most of those things did, haha..